# Error opening project file in VS2012

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.5, csproj

The following error is being returned when i try to open a colleagues MVC application in VS2012.

[image]

when i click on "OK" - i am not able to open any of the files within the environment.

I am able to open this project in other PCs where VS2012 is installed.

can anyone help me understand why this is happening and a resolution to this?

Comment: Is .NET 4.5 on your machine? Did you try the second radio button?

Comment: yes .net 4.5 was on my machine. A strange issue did occur when i attempted to create a new MVC application. MVC4 was not available as an option. The 2nd radio button - did not work either

Comment: Sounds like your installation maybe faulty. Reinstall MVC4, create a new MVC4 project and target it for 4.5. Do you have any issues with other 4.5 projects or only this project?

Comment: I believe so - i just did not want to waste my time uninstalling and then re-installing - if i thought there was a quick fix for this. - this is happening in VS2012 Ultimate f.y.i

Comment: This is our first movement into MVC .net4.5 projects - we used VS2010 before this.

Comment: i re-installed VS2012 with MVC4.. all 'seems' ok and is playing.. i'm just thinking because i installed MVC4 on VS2010 - did it skip over its installation when i upgraded to VS2012 - therefore not available to me. anyhows this is now resolved. Thanks Dave

Comment: I moved my comments to an answer. I actually have no idea why this was the case I'm afraid!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no problem with VS2012 and MVC4. If you can't even create a new MVC4 project, then the you know the fault is not with the project your colleague wrote but something with your current setup.

You may be able to just redownload / install MVC4 and Visual Studio!

Answer (score 0):

just check once again about .net4.5 and mvc4 is properly installed or not.try your friends laptop who installed vs2012 with the same project.if sucessfull then there is a fault in your installation.

Answer (score -1):

Try a repair of VS seems something strange appened